# Spark Data set merge two rows based on filter and drop remaining one

Tags: apache-spark

I am only 4 days old with learning spark and writing a spark job with **JAVA 8** & I need to merge two or more rows in a dataset into one based on a specific condition. Also, need to drop the duplicate columns

dataset.show()

```
ID | branch | name    | role | age
1  | HQ     | Harry   | DEV  | 24
1  | Berlin | Harry   | QA   | 24
1  | Hungary| Harry   | BA   | 24
2  | HQ     | Chris   | Prod | 39
2  | Chime  | Chris   | Prod | 39
2  | Cornell| Chris   | Acc  | 39
2  | Chappel| Chris   |      | 39
```

Output required:

```
ID | branch | name    | role        | age 
1  | HQ     | Harry   | "DEV,QA,BA"| 24
2  | HQ     | Chris   | "Prod,Acc" | 39
```

The condition is, merge the rows with this logic:

Merge the rows with the same ID and concatenate/combine "role" column (without duplicates or blank values) for all rows into the row where branch = "HQ".

Keep the row where the column branch is "HQ" and drop rest of the others.

I wrote this bit:

```
   Dataset<Row> mergeRoles(SparkSession sparkSession, Dataset<Row> dataset) {
        WindowSpec overCategory = Window.partitionBy("ID");
        dataset = dataset.withColumn("temp_role", collect_list("role").over(overCategory));
        dataset.createOrReplaceTempView("tmp");
        dataset = sparkSession.sql("SELECT *, mergeRole(temp_role) as role FROM tmp")
                              .dropDuplicates("ID");
        return dataset;
    }
```

And wrote a UDF `mergeRole` which merges the values in "role" column. But unfortunately, I can't use `createOrReplaceTempView` due to some memory issues. Please help, need to find a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

### Load the test data

```java
    String data = "ID | branch | name    | role | age\n" +
                "1  | HQ     | Harry   | DEV  | 24\n" +
                "1  | Berlin | Harry   | QA   | 24\n" +
                "1  | Hungary| Harry   | BA   | 24\n" +
                "2  | HQ     | Chris   | Prod | 39\n" +
                "2  | Chime  | Chris   | Prod | 39\n" +
                "2  | Cornell| Chris   | Acc  | 39\n" +
                "2  | Chappel| Chris   |      | 39";

        List<String> list1 = Arrays.stream(data.split(System.lineSeparator()))
                .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split("\\|"))
                        .map(s1 -> s1.replaceAll("^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$", ""))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(","))
                )
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        Dataset<Row> dataset = spark.read()
                .option("header", true)
                .option("inferSchema", true)
                .option("sep", ",")
                .csv(spark.createDataset(list1, Encoders.STRING()));
        dataset.show(false);
        dataset.printSchema();

        /**
         * +---+-------+-----+----+---+
         * |ID |branch |name |role|age|
         * +---+-------+-----+----+---+
         * |1  |HQ     |Harry|DEV |24 |
         * |1  |Berlin |Harry|QA  |24 |
         * |1  |Hungary|Harry|BA  |24 |
         * |2  |HQ     |Chris|Prod|39 |
         * |2  |Chime  |Chris|Prod|39 |
         * |2  |Cornell|Chris|Acc |39 |
         * |2  |Chappel|Chris|null|39 |
         * +---+-------+-----+----+---+
         *
         * root
         *  |-- ID: integer (nullable = true)
         *  |-- branch: string (nullable = true)
         *  |-- name: string (nullable = true)
         *  |-- role: string (nullable = true)
         *  |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
         */
```

### fetch the set of roles for `HQ` branch

```java
        dataset.withColumn("role", collect_set(
                when(trim(col("role")).equalTo(lit("")), lit(null)).otherwise(col("role"))
        ).over(Window.partitionBy("ID")))
                .where("branch='HQ'")
                .show(false);
        /**
         * +---+------+-----+-------------+---+
         * |ID |branch|name |role         |age|
         * +---+------+-----+-------------+---+
         * |2  |HQ    |Chris|[Prod, Acc]  |39 |
         * |1  |HQ    |Harry|[QA, BA, DEV]|24 |
         * +---+------+-----+-------------+---+
         */
```